# Vue Routing Issue

Tags: vue.js, routes

I am trying to go through a tutorial (link below) to learn vue and firebase. There is a main dashboard page with a list of employees (the "Dashboard"), and I have gotten that to display a list of employees from firebase. Each employee has the following router link to go to the employee page to see details:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<li v-for="employee in employees" v-bind:key="employee.id" class="collection-item">
        <div class="chip">{{employee.dept}}</div>
        {{employee.employee_id}}:{{employee.name}}
        <router-link class="secondary-content"
          v-bind:to="{name: 'view-employee', params: {employee_id: employee.employee_id}}"
        >
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </router-link>
      </li>
```

When the Dashboard component loads, or I click a link next to an employee on the page, nothing happens and I get the following warning:

> [vue-router] missing param for named route "view-employee": Expected
>   "employee" to be defined

```js
Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: '/new',
      name: 'new-employee',
      component: NewEmployee
    },
    {
      path: '/edit/:employee-id',
      name: 'edit-employee',
      component: EditEmployee
    },
    {
      path: '/:employee-id',
      name: 'view-employee',
      component: ViewEmployee
    }
  ]
})
```

But neither the view employee or edit employee paths have worked as intended. For example, I need to type the URL "localhost:8081/#/edit/:employee-id" just to see just a blank Edit Employee page. And I needed to type localhost:8081/#/:employee-id in order to see just a blank View Employee page. Now that I have added the get code to View Employee, going to localhost:8081/#/:employee-id gives me this error:

> Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was
>   undefined.

But that's because it does recognize "to.params.employee_id" because I am not getting there from the employee list.

This is a relevant portion of a video in the tutorial:

https://youtu.be/rUz4oz7dTno?list=PLillGF-RfqbYsOOycB67Raf9dwmL6Y31M&t=638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might be the different between dash character and underscore character (`employee-id` is different with `employee_id`)

You can try changing your routes:

```
Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: '/new',
      name: 'new-employee',
      component: NewEmployee
    },
    {
      path: '/edit/:employee_id',
      name: 'edit-employee',
      component: EditEmployee
    },
    {
      path: '/:employee_id',
      name: 'view-employee',
      component: ViewEmployee
    }
  ]
})
```

or change in router-link

```
<router-link class="secondary-content"
  v-bind:to="{name: 'view-employee', params: {'employee-id': employee.employee_id}}">
  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</router-link>
```

Comment: Changing the routes worked! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!